# React native Could not determine java version from '10'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, java-10

I am having a hard time trying to configure my emulator with react native. I already have the emulator installed but can't properly run the statement: `react-native run-android` this is the error I keep getting. (p.s. there seems to be no solutions in the troubleshoot. I have tried to change the gradle-properties which was ineffective)

```
C:\Users\Dell\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\Dell\AwesomeProject\node_modules (31ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '10'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: looks like a bug in react-native, may be they don't support 10 yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. After upgrading to Ubuntu Bionic which comes with Java 10 which is not supported by react-native.

I'm using the following script now:

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
react-native run-android
```

I change the env path to Java 8 and run the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading your gradle or downgrading java ... I would prefer upgrading your gradle.

Upgrading our Gradle

1 .Modify android/build.gradle :

Add google() inside repositories

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // add google() here
        google()
```

Update com.android.tools.build.gradle to 3.1.0

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
      // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
      // update from 2.2.3 to 3.1.0 
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

Add google() inside repositories after dependencies :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
    allprojects {
      repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        // add googgle() here
        google()
```

2. Add android.enableAapt2=false to android/gradle.properties

   android.enableAapt2=false // < ---  add here
   android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
   MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
   MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
3. Update gradle version in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties :

   // from version 2.14.1
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
   // change to 4.4
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
4. Runreact-native run-android. (This might take a while since it’ll be downloading the updated gradle version.)